# How can I catch and log details about exceptions when rendering an SSRS report?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, webforms, ssrs-2017

I work with applications in ASP.Net.  Some are MVC, some are WebForms, most use .Net Framework, a few use .Net Core 3; almost **all** of them have reports.  Sometimes when rendering an SSRS report in Viewer.aspx, something goes wrong.  It might be that the report times out, or that there is an error like this:

```
  An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
  Query execution failed for dataset 'dsMyDataset'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
  Procedure or function 'spMyStoredProc' expects parameter '@MissingParameter', which was not supplied.
```

While I can see that error in real time if I'm the one running the report, I'd like two things:

1. Is this level of detail logged anywhere?  When I look in the report server database at the ExecutionLog3 view, I can see a status of "rsProcessingAborted", but I really want those other details too.
2. Is there a way for me to catch that error and call some code, either to notify me or log the situation?

To demonstrate, take any report that is currently working, add a parameter to the stored procedure that it uses, and then run the report.

Comment: add a try catch and/or a log event in your stored procedure, then decide how you want to deal with the errors/logs . e.g. send an email to you, add to error log table etc.

Comment: @JobesK unfortunately my try/catch/log in the stored proc never gets hit in these cases -- if you call a proc with invalid parameters, the proc doesn't run and the caller has to handle the error.

Comment: the program should spit out the error, if you want you could also make the parms optional